# Problema con PHP y JSON para graficar en HighCharts

Tags: php, json

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy intentando graficar en HighCharts usando datos en formato `json`, pero al momento de ejecutar el código no se visualiza nada, la pantalla queda en blanco, para realizar dicha acción usé `php` para la lectura del archivo `json` de la siguiente manera:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Tráfico mensual</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {


        $(document).ready(function() {
           Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#tiempoReal').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, 
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        <?php

                        $contenido = file_get_contents("datos.json");
                        $contenido = $contenido;
                        $datos = json_decode($contenido, true);
                        $hay = count($datos["sensores"]);
                        $sensores = $datos["sensores"];

                        ?>


                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var google = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = <?php

                                foreach($sensores as $se){
                                    echo "$se[valor]";
                                }

                                ?>
                            google.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Distancia Actualizada segundo a segundo'
            },
            subtitle:{
                text: 'Tiempo Real'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Distancia'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Google.com',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: 0
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });
});


    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <div style="border-top:1px solid #CDCDCD;margin:10px;padding:0;clear:both;"></div>

    <!-- div que contendrá la gráfica a tiempo real -->
    <div id="tiempoReal" style="height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

dicho el código `php` en un aparte si funciona yo lo probé pero no entiendo cual es la razón por la cual no me permite tomar los datos, por cierto, este el archivo **datos.json**:

```
{
"sensores": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nombre": "infrarrojo",
        "valor": "22.5"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "nombre": "infrarrojo",
        "valor": "30"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "nombre": "infrarrojo",
        "valor": "16.5"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "nombre": "infrarrojo",
        "valor": "22.5"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "nombre": "infrarrojo",
        "valor": "30"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "nombre": "infrarrojo",
        "valor": "22.5"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "nombre": "infrarrojo",
        "valor": "30"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: el último json es el que te genera el php que tienes incrustado?

Comment: Sii el json que coloque al ultimo es el resultado del codigo php, pero no me ejecuta la gráfica

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido a StackOverflow,

He podido ver que le falta un ";" en la línea donde asignas el valor a Y.
El código quedaría así:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Tráfico mensual</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {


        $(document).ready(function() {
           Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#tiempoReal').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, 
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        <?php

                        $contenido = file_get_contents("datos.json");
                        $contenido = $contenido;
                        $datos = json_decode($contenido, true);
                        $hay = count($datos["sensores"]);
                        $sensores = $datos["sensores"];

                        ?>


                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var google = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = <?php

                                foreach($sensores as $se){
                                    echo "$se[valor];";
                                }

                                ?>
                            google.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Distancia Actualizada segundo a segundo'
            },
            subtitle:{
                text: 'Tiempo Real'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Distancia'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Google.com',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: 0
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });
});


    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <div style="border-top:1px solid #CDCDCD;margin:10px;padding:0;clear:both;"></div>

    <!-- div que contendrá la gráfica a tiempo real -->
    <div id="tiempoReal" style="height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

Comment: Disculpa como podría hacer para que la gráfica me muestre los datos que se vayan ingresando a la base de datos, porque actualmente solo tiene los valores son estáticos y al momento de ingresar otro dato no cambia. Te agradezco mucho por la corrección del código ya ejecuta la gráfica

Comment: @DiegoGonzález Tendrías que hacer una petición ajax a tu mismo archivo que te retorna el json, destruir tu gráfica y volverla a instanaciar-crear.

Comment: Fernando Torres hice otra pregunta en la cual saqué otro código, sin embargo no me genera los valores en tiempo real sale mal, este es el enlace, podrías revisarlo y ver que se encuentra mal por favor
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321242/problemas-con-highcharts