# Problemas con HighCharts

Tags: php, mysql, json

Alguien podría ayudarme con la siguiente inquietud, tengo que graficar valores de una base de datos, ya he realizado la conexión y sé que se está ejecutando correctamente la consulta y la transformación de esa consulta en un archivo json, dicho esto, este es el código que toma los valores de la base de datos y los transforma en el archivo `datos2.php`:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$host='localhost';
$dbname='bdd_embebidos';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host",$user,$pass);
switch($_GET['Consultar']){
// Buscar Último Dato
case 1:
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT valor as y FROM sensor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
echo $json;
    break; 
// Buscar Todos los datos
default:
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT valor as y FROM sensor ORDER BY id ASC");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
echo $json;
break;
}
?>
```

Como mencioné con anterioridad este archivo php me consulta a la base de datos y me trae los datos en formato `json`. Por otra parte este es el código que estoy utilizando para graficar los valores:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
   <script src="exporting.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
     <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0     auto"></div>   

  <script>
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ultimox;
    var ultimoy;

    $.ajax({
            url: "datos2.php",
            type: 'get',
            success: function(DatosRecuperados) {
            $.each(DatosRecuperados, function(i,o){

                if (o.y) {DatosRecuperados[i].y = parseFloat(o.y);}
            });

            time = (new Date()).getTime()

            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1){
                setx((time + i * 1000).x);
            }


            sety(DatosRecuperados[(DatosRecuperados.length)-1].y);

            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart:{
                        type: 'spline',
                        animation: Highcharts.svg,
                        marginRight: 10,
                        events: {load: function () {series = this.series[0];}}
                    },
                title:{text: 'Live random data'},
                xAxis:{tickPixelInterval: 150},
                yAxis:{title: {text: 'Value'},
                    plotLines: [{value: 0,width: 1,color: '#808080'}]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            Highcharts.numberFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                        }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{ name: 'Random data', data:DatosRecuperados}]
            });

    }});
});
      setInterval(function () {
            $.get( "datos2.php?Consultar=1", function( UltimosDatos ) {
                var varlocalx=(new Date()).getTime();
                var varlocaly=parseFloat(UltimosDatos[0].y);

             if((getx()!=varlocalx)&&(gety()!=varlocaly)){

                series.addPoint([varlocalx, varlocaly], true, true);
                setx(varlocalx);
                sety(varlocaly);
            }
       });}, 1000);

      function getx(){return ultimox;}
      function gety(){return ultimoy;}
      function setx(x){ultimox=x;}
      function sety(y){ultimoy=y;}
});
 </script>
 </body>
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar este código grafica pero no me actualiza en tiempo real, primero me sale una gráfica con todos los valores ingresados en la base de datos:
[image: Se cargan los valores de la base de datos normalmente]
Sin embargo, no se funciona los intervalos de tiempo que mando en el eje x, se queda estático, además cuando ingreso otro datos queda de la siguiente manera:
[image: La grafica se desfasa y sale de esa forma y no se actualiza correctamente con el valor que le envío desde la base de datos]

Comment: Hola, echa un vistazo a esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560993/auto-update-highcharts-with-ajax

Comment: Rayos la verdad lo intenté poner al código pero no me funcionó, de casualidad tendrás otro enlace que pudiera revisar